# Unexpected error when using a reference of vector in a third pary function

Tags: c++, function, vector, reference

I am supposed to input an array of values for `x` in the below third party function.

```
bool MyNLP::get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, double* x,
                           bool init_z, double* z_L, double* z_U,
                           Index m, bool init_lambda,
                           double* lambda)
{
      //example
      x[0] =0.5;
      x[1] =1.5;

      //similarly other values also initialized.

      return true;
}
```

I got the correct result.

**NEXT CASE**

Now instead of entering values of `x` directly, I used vector of values which is a member of class `nlp`.

```
class nlp
{
std::vector<double> m_val;

public:
std::vector<double>& get_val()
{
     m_val.push_back(0.5);
     m_val.push_back(1.5);
     return m_val;
}
}
```

I called function `get_val` inside the thied party function.

```
bool MyNLP::get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, double* x,
                           bool init_z, double* z_L, double* z_U,
                           Index m, bool init_lambda,
                           double* lambda)
{
      //example
      //x = &(m_nlp->get_val()).at(0);
      std::vector<double>& values = m_nlp->get_val();
      x = &values.at(0);
      assert(x[0] == 0.5);
      assert(x[1] == 1.5);

      //similarly other values also initialized.

      return true;
}
```

I initialized the `x` with the same values as before in the first case, but the output was different. My assertions didn't fail too. I don't have clue about what is happening here.

What could  be the reason for two different outputs?

Comment: `==` is not appropriate for comparing floating point values. It would be better to do an epsilon test. If you are still having trouble please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @M.M While that's true in general, `0.5` and `1.5` have exact representations, so this case shouldn't fail.

Comment: In your second example you don't write any values to where the original `x` is pointing (you just point the local `x` somewhere else), maybe you intended `double *p = &m_nlp->get_val().at(0); x[0] = p[0]; x[1] = p[1];` or something

Comment: @M.M I pointed `x` to the address of first element of vector and ensured that array `x` contain the exact element I wanted, by making assertion

Comment: Yeah. Your two cases do different things. The first one writes values to where `x` is pointing. The second one makes `x` point somewhere else.  You didn't post a complete program, but I assume you have some other function that allocates memory and then passes the address of that memory to this function, expecting values to be written into it.  Your first case does write values into it, your second case doesn't.

Comment: @M.M He's trying to set `x` to point to the array that holds the data of the vector returned by `get_val()`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, and the code successfully does that, I'm trying to explain how that is different to writing values to where `x` was originally pointing (I conjecture that the calling code expects this)

Comment: Right. The second program is simply modifying the local variable `x`, not storing anything into the caller's array.

Comment: I assumed the problem he was having was that the asserts were failing.

Comment: This is what happens when there's no MCVE

Comment: **What could be the reason for two different outputs?** The code you posted doesn't produce any output, other that possible `assert()` failures. What output are you talking about?

Comment: @Barmar, There is  rest of program. I haven't changed any modification other than this in the program. So I hoped the exact results since assertions didn't fail.

Comment: @M.M Ok, Now I understood your point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first version you're indirecting through `x` to modify the elements of the caller's array.

In the second program you're reassigning the local pointer variable `x` to point to the data in the vector. This has no effect on the caller's array, since `x` was passed by value, not by reference.

You need to copy the values from the vector to the array.

```
bool MyNLP::get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, double* x,
                           bool init_z, double* z_L, double* z_U,
                           Index m, bool init_lambda,
                           double* lambda)
{
      //example
      //x = &(m_nlp->get_val()).at(0);
      std::vector<double>& values = m_nlp->get_val();
      for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        x[i] = values[i];
      }

      return true;
}
```

Another option is to change the code so `x` is passed by referenced: `double *&x`. But this will require changes to the callers: they shouldn't allocate memory for the pointer they pass, because it will not be freed (unless you add `delete[] x` to this function). And they'll have to pass a pointer variable, not an array that's implicitly decayed to a pointer.

Comment: I understood my mistake, although couldn't understand the alternative option you gave. And I cannot change the caller function too. Thanks